# Column to ROW IN ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Please share some SQL ans for the below req:

I want to return all of the rows in a single-column table as a single row, with the value from each row pivoted into a column in the output.

```
SAMPLE_COLUMN_DATA
------------------
    SAM ANDREW
    JOHN MATHEW
    CHRIS JOE
    JANE PATRICK
```

OUTPUT NEEDED AS BELOW:

```
col1       |col2        |col3      |col4
------------------------------------------------
SAM ANDREW |JOHN MATHEW |CHRIS JOE |JANE PATRICK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understood the question, it is a matter of *aggregation* (`listagg`, with pipe character as a separator):

```
SQL> with test (sample_column_data) as
  2    (select 'SAM ANDREW'   from dual union all
  3     select 'JOHN MATHEW'  from dual union all
  4     select 'CHRIS JOE'    from dual union all
  5     select 'JANE PATRICK' from dual
  6    )
  7  select listagg(sample_column_data, '|') within group (order by null) result
  8  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CHRIS JOE|JANE PATRICK|JOHN MATHEW|SAM ANDREW

SQL>
```

---

If they have to be "true" separate columns, then you could use `ROWNUM` with aggregation along with `CASE`. This, of course, doesn't scale at all.

```
SQL> with test (sample_column_data) as
  2    (select 'SAM ANDREW'   from dual union all
  3     select 'JOHN MATHEW'  from dual union all
  4     select 'CHRIS JOE'    from dual union all
  5     select 'JANE PATRICK' from dual
  6    )
  7  select
  8    max(case when rownum = 1 then sample_column_data end) col1,
  9    max(case when rownum = 2 then sample_column_data end) col2,
 10    max(case when rownum = 3 then sample_column_data end) col3,
 11    max(case when rownum = 4 then sample_column_data end) col4
 12  from test;

COL1         COL2         COL3       COL4
------------ ------------ ---------- ------------
SAM ANDREW   JOHN MATHEW  CHRIS JOE  JANE PATRICK

SQL>
```

Comment: i have used this pipeline symbol to differencite between columns.. Thats is not result what i am expecting.. what i need is , if you select a table, how you see the columns from that table ... in the same way i would like to see these values as separate columns. please let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: I edited the answer and added another example; have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you have one column with values (names)..

In that case, you can use `listagg()` function:

```
select 
        listagg(SAMPLE_COLUMN_DATA,'|') within group 
         (order by SAMPLE_COLUMN_DATA) 
from dual;
```